# WPF IPAddress Dependency property

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a dependency property called LocalIPProperty as a string dependency property. All is good but when I afterwards use the UserControl in an application and change that LocalIPProperty to a non-IP text in VS property window the VS property window shows the default IP-string (127.0.0.1) and in XAML it adds :LocalIP="sdahashfah" and then when I try to run the application I get XalmParserException.

I also tried to just simply create the LocalIPProperty as IPAddress Dependency property, but in application with the UserControl I coudn't change the IPAddress.

What I want is that when I set LocalIP to a non-IP string in VS properties window the value remains unchanged.

What I have now is:

```
public static DependencyProperty LocalIPProperty = DependencyProperty.
            Register("LocalIP", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("127.0.0.1"), IPPropertyValidate);

        private static bool IPPropertyValidate(object value)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress.Parse((string)value);
            }
            catch { return false; }
            return true;
        }

        [Description("IP for listening."), Category("Address")]
        public string LocalIP
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LocalIPProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocalIPProperty, value); }
        }
```

Thanks for any efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in the VS editor. It looks like it's trying to set the invalid property value that you're putting in but doesn't know what to do when it gets back a false value from validation. It may be attempting to set it as a design time value to be ignored at runtime but not outputting the correct syntax.